# Why $M_n$ $\not\cong$ $O_n\times T_n$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I would like to know why $M_n$ $\not\cong$ $O_n\times T_n$, where $M_n$ is the group of isometries of $\mathbb R^n$, $O_n$ is the group of orthogonal matrices, and $T_n$ is the group of translations in $\mathbb R^n$.

**My attempt:** Can I show that one side is abelian, while the other group is not abelian? How do I go about doing that? Can I begin by showing that their centers are not isomorphic?

Thanks.

Comment: If $M_n \cong O_n \times T_n$, then $O_n$ would be normal in $M_n$, but it is not.

Comment: @Prahlad Vaidyanathan Why is the "if" part of your statement true? Could you clarify?

Comment: The problem is that translations do not commute with orthogonal matrices in general. If you write a group as a product of two subgroups, those subgroups must commute.

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan I don't quite follow. It can be true that $A\cong C\times B$, but there is an embedding $C\hookrightarrow A$ which has non-normal image.

Comment: Any actual answers out there? I'm just more confused now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $A \in O_n, t_b \in T_n$ you can check that
$$
t_b\circ A \circ t_b^{-1} = t_{b-Ab}\circ A
$$
In particular, if we choose $b$ and $A$ such that $b-Ab\neq 0$, then we see that $O_n$ is not normal in $M_n$.

Now suppose $M_n \cong O_n\times T_n$, then
$$
O_n \cong O_n\times \{t_0\} \triangleleft M_n
$$

Comment: I disagree with this answer. It's possible that $M_n\cong O_n\times T_n$, but that $O_n$ embeds non-normally into $M_n$.

Answer (score 0):

$M_n$ is actually what is called a *semidirect product* $O_n \ltimes T_n$, with respect to the usual action of $O_n$ on $T_n \cong \mathbb{R}^n$. See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidirect_product) for more information.